# Script to find sequences of lowercase letters joined with underscore or dash

Tags: powershell, regex

I am newbie in writing scripts in powershell, and even more in regular expressions, please help with the implementation.

example:

```
PS > .\test.ps1 "A Balrog is a powerful fictional monster in Middle-earth."
return: Middle-earth
```

or

```
PS >.\test.ps1 "The symbol underscore, also called low_line or low dash."
return: low_line
```

of course I tried to find a solution for this problem, here is my solution:

```
#$data = $args[0]

$p = '\w*[-_]\w*'

Select-String -Path .\content.txt -Pattern $p | % {$_ -match $p; $matches.Value}

Write-Output $matches
```

===========================================
Update: Solution found

Comment: actually regex will be like this:  '\w*[-_]\w*', 

this greate [link](https://regex101.com/r/AuWxVu/16/) come with help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = $args[0]

$pattern = '\w*[-_]\w*'

$matches = [regex]::Matches($data, $pattern).Value

Write-Output $matches
```